# Is it possible to preview an item linked in chat?

Tags: diablo-iii

In a manner similar to how it is in World of Warcraft, is there any way to use an item that has been linked in chat to preview how it would look on you character?

In WoW this is done by shift clicking on the item in chat, and it would bring up a version of your character that is identical to you, but with whatever item that you shift clicked replacing the item you have of the same slot. This could be repeated with more items until your entire appearance was altered.

Is anything like this possible in Diablo 3?

Comment: Derp.  Misread.  You mean preview how it looks on the character, not preview the item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at present you can only compare the items to other items, it does not change your model's appearance.